# .container not responding to media query for iPad

Tags: ipad, css, responsive-design, media-queries, containers

I've done a fair amount of research on this, but have been unsuccessful in figuring this out. I'm working with a responsive site using the lessframework.css for the responsive grid. It is not properly snapping to any tablet size between 768px and 1024px. When I inspect the elements at that screen size, it appears that the .container is not resizing between those dimensions. However, I don't see anywhere in my css where this is designated to a specific px size, therefore overriding it. I picked this project up from a previous developer, and I am new to responsive code. Any help that can be given would be a huge help. Thank you!

Website is www.mereo.co

Here's a sample of the code from the lessframework.css grid:

```
/*  Default 8-column layout
    60 px columns, 24 px gutters, 60 px margins, 768 px total
    ---------------------------------------------------------
    1     2      3      4      5      6      7      8     
    60px  144px  228px  312px  396px  480px  564px  648px   */

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}


#if-logged-in {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    background: #000;
    color: #aaa;
    font-size: 10px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
    #if-logged-in .container {
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }
    #if-logged-in p {
        margin: 0;
    }
    #if-logged-in a:link,
    #if-logged-in a:visited {
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    #if-logged-in a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    #if-logged-in a:active {
        text-decoration: underline;
        margin-bottom: -1px;
    }


.container {
    /*padding: 0 60px;*/
    width: 768px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
    #header-image {
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
        /* HEADER IMAGE
            full size - 1068x300
            8 column layout resized to 890x250 displayed at 648x250
            5 column layout resized to 534x150 displayed at 396x150
            3 column layout resized to 365x100 displayed at 228x100
         */
        #header-image img {
            width: 890px;
            height: 250px;
            margin-left: -121px;
            padding: 0;
        }
    #content {
        width: 356px; /* 5 columns */
        margin: 0;
        padding: 20px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #sidebar {
        width: 184px; /* 3 columns */
        margin: 0;
        padding: 20px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

::selection {
    background: #c6d8cd;
}
::-moz-selection {
    background: #c6d8cd;
}
img::selection {
    background: transparent;
}
img::-moz-selection {
    background: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the `.container { }` styles specific to that ipad size and resolution should be inside the media query you have there. So if the container should be 400px wide on an iPad, then your code should be:

```
/* iPad 1 & 2 (landscape) */
@media (device-width: 1024px) and (device-height: 768px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    .container {
        width: 400px;
        /* all other .container styles specific to the iPad 2 in landscape should go here */
    }
    #if-logged-in {
        /* other styles go in their respective selector in the media query */
    }
}
```

Don't forget that there is an iPad without the retina display, and one with which means if you have any background images or svg images loading from css those should be set to point to the assets that are 2x resolution to look good on retina iPads inside the retina iPad media query.